# Changing variable in double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I have a double integral in the following form;

$$
\int_{0}^{t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{H(\xi,\tau)}{(\xi-\tau)^2+1}d\xi d\tau
$$
where $H$ is an arbitrary smooth function. Can I change the variable $\xi$ as $\xi-\tau=k$? Since the new variable also contains the other integration variable, I am not sure I am allowed to such a change.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{H(\xi,\tau)}{(\xi-\tau)^2+1}\mathrm{d}\xi \mathrm{d}\tau:=\int_{\tau=0}^{\tau=t}\int_{\xi\to-\infty}^{\xi\to\infty}\frac{H(\xi,\tau)}{(\xi-\tau)^2+1}\mathrm{d}\xi \mathrm{d}\tau$$

$$k=\xi-\tau\;\Rightarrow \xi=k+\tau\;\Rightarrow\;\mathrm{d}\xi=\mathrm{d}k$$

$$\int_{\tau=0}^{\tau=t}\int_{k\to-\infty-\tau}^{k\to\infty-\tau}\frac{H(k+\tau,\tau)}{k^2+1}\mathrm{d}k \mathrm{d}\tau=:\int_{0}^{t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{H(k+\tau,\tau)}{k^2+1}\mathrm{d}k \mathrm{d}\tau\\
$$

Answer (score 1):

The operation you are performing, is a special case of transformation change. While changing the coordinate system $\underline{x}$ to $\underline{\tilde x}$, you need to (1) represent the integration domain according to the new system of coordinates and (2) find and apply the Jacobian matrix, defined as following
$$
\frac{d\underline{x}}{d\underline{\tilde x}}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial \tilde x_1}&\cdots &\frac{\partial x_1}{\partial \tilde x_n}\\
\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial \tilde x_1}&\cdots &\frac{\partial x_2}{\partial \tilde x_n}\\
\\\vdots&\cdots&\vdots\\
\frac{\partial x_n}{\partial \tilde x_1}&\cdots& \frac{\partial x_n}{\partial \tilde x_n}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
using the following identity
$$
\int f(\underline x)d\underline x=\int f(\underline { \tilde x})\det(J(\underline{ \tilde x}))d\underline{ \tilde x}.
$$
In your example, $\det(J(\underline{ \tilde x}))=1$. Hence
$$
\int_{0}^{t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{H(\xi,\tau)}{(\xi-\tau)^2+1}d\xi d\tau
=
\int_{0}^{t}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{H(\xi+\tau,\tau)}{\xi^2+1}d\xi d\tau.
$$